# (Electron) How to open/close a window without making it the active application?

Tags: macos, electron, window, focus

Raycast is a perfect example of this. I can open the window with a global shortcut and type in it. When I open/close the window, the application in the top left (macos) doesn't change. How do I do this in electron?

Answer (score 0):

hide the dock with app.dock.hide().